# Правильна ли такая функция?

Tags: c++, функции, инспекция-кода, параметры

Всех приветствую.Только начал разбираться с функциями.Подскажите пожалуйста, правильно ли сделал функцию и передачу параметров?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <math.h>
using namespace std;
void Obratn(int a[], int b[], int n);
int main()
{
    int a[10], b[10], i, n;
    cout << "Vvedite razmer massiva: ";
    cin >> n;
    cout << "\nVvedite massiv:\n";
    for (i = 0; i<n; i++)
    {
        cout << "Vvedite a[" << i << "]= ";
        cin >> a[i];
    }
    cout << "\nMassiv a:\n";
    for (i = 0; i<n; i++)
        cout << " " << a[i];
    cout << endl;
    Obratn(a, b,n);
    system("pause");
}

void Obratn(int a[],int b[], int n)
{

    for (int i = 0; i<n; i++)
        b[n - i - 1] = a[i];
    for (int i = 0; i<n; i++){
        a[i] = b[i];
        cout << " " << a[i];
    }
    cout << endl;

}
```

Comment: а массив b зачем нужен?

Answer (score 3):

Ну, я бы на вашем месте сделал так:

```
void Obratn(int a[], int n)
{
    for (int i = 0, j = n - 1; i < j; ++i, --j)
    {
        int tmp = a[i];
        a[i] = a[j];
        a[j] = tmp;
    }
}
```

Это - к тому, что не нужно использовать лишнюю память там, где без нее можно обойтись.

И еще - я убрал отсюда вывод на экран - потому что каждая функция должна заниматься одним делом. Эта - обращением массива. Выводом должна заниматься другая...

P.S. Да, и после `cin >> n;` следовало бы проверить, что у вас хватит памяти в маcсиве `a[10]`, т.е. что введенный размер не превышает 10.

Answer (score 3):

С этой функцией есть несколько проблем:

- запись вида `int a[]` вводит в заблуждение, так как тип `a` на самом деле `int *`, соответственно лучше указать тип явно

```cpp
void Obratn(int * a, int * b, int n);
```

- не соблюдается const-correctness, ни один из параметров не помечен как `const` хотя параметры внутри функции не изменяются, соответственно лучше записть

```cpp
void Obratn(int * const a, int * const b, int const n);
```

- сырые указатели вообще лучше не использовать, вместо них использовать `array_view` (какую-нибудь реализацию), причем массив тут по факту нужен только один

```cpp
void Obratn(array_view<int> const a);
```

- транслит в именах функций - это безобразие, так же как и ничего не значащие наименования переменных из одной буквы

```cpp
void Reverse(array_view<int> const items);
```

- эта функция вполне может быть реализована без выбрасывания исключений, соответственно можно добавить спецификатор `noexcept`

```cpp
void Reverse(array_view<int> const items) noexcept;
```